# How to pass whole array of words given in command line arguments direct to function?

Tags: c, command-line, linked-list, command-line-arguments, singly-linked-list

I want to ask is there a diffrent to pass words from comand line array of strings to this function other than this:

```
//input given: $> ./main tail degree sheet nose noise base boy
//declaration of function: int ll_insert_words(struct linked_list_t* ll, int N, ...);
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linked_list.h"
int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Not enough arguments");
        return 9;
    }
    struct linked_list_t* ll = ll_create();
    if (ll == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory");
        return 8;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        ll_insert_words(ll, 1, *(argv + 1 + i));
    }
    ll_display(ll);
    ll_clear(ll);
    free(ll);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know how can I pass the array directly to function. By that I mean:

```
ll_insert_words(ll, 12, "list", "among", "sharp", "has", "coat", "consonant", "old", "trouble", "require", "wear", "band", "real");
```

But to swap all "list" etc. to the array.

Comment: note that argv[0] contains the script name

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I know this that's why I used `*(argv + 1 + i)` to pass words only

Comment: Why would you need a linked list? Just passing `(argv+1, argc-1)` to your function would suffice.

Comment: @wildplasser My assigment requires it, the code I posted completes my task but I wanted to know for myself is there another way to pass it to function.

Comment: You won’t be able to pass the command line arguments to a varargs function (one with a `, ...)` at the end of its signature) easily.  That is more or less undoable, though maybe the Foreign Function Interface Library (`libffi`) can do it, though it is not standard on most systems. The `main()` function already deals with a variable number of arguments; your code should follow its lead, probably.

Comment: "how can I pass the array directly to function." cannot happen without significant changes to `ll_insert_words()`.  Post `ll_insert_words()` code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you for your interest, but I have already read about `libffi` and I know that at the moment I prefer to stick to this method: ')

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass  a (char**) pointer to the function. Change the function declaration to:

```
int ll_insert_words(struct linked_list_t* ll, char** words, int number_of_words);
```

And then call it with these parameters:

```
ll_insert_words(ll, argv, argc);
```

Then in the function write something along these lines:

```
for (i = 0; i < number_of_words; i++)
{
    ll_insert(ll, words[i]);
}
```

Comment: I've got valist interpreted in the function so I don't need to it like this, and your code won't work for me! [Valist](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html)

Comment: Why don't you use va_list in main function too then?

Comment: Also if you pass it like this: `ll_insert_words(ll, argv, argc);` argv[0] contains the script name which I don't want inside my data :)

Comment: @MerMonkey: ... then do `ll_insert_words(ll, argv+1, argc-1);`

Comment: @alk this also won't work I'm adding copy of the word given to the list and I need to alocate it inside the function. When I tried to use your method words are not readable (char* word=va_arg(list,char*) got no value) and I got error: Access violation reading location.